# Radio button problems ajax rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, jquery

I am endeavoring to create a the option for users to select an image as the album cover for the image's index view (`@image.each do |image|`).  However, for this to be effective, the radio button's for has to span across each of the images.  The only way I could think of to accomplish this was to set a `radio_button_tag` in the `@image.each do |image|` loop.  This does not implement a `form` tag.

I want to be able to change the `:albumcover` field of the Images table to the image's id(got that part) *when the radio button is pressed.*

My attempted code is below.  I get this error when I load the page though.

**Error**

```
undefined method `ajaxUpdate_admin_album_image' for #<#<Class:0x102450300>:0x1021e94b8>`
```

**jQuery** *(images.js.erb)*

```
$(function(){
    $('#albumcover_tag').bind('click', function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'PUT',
            url: '<%= ajaxUpdate_admin_album_image(:admin, @album, @image) %>',
            data: $('#albumcover_tag').val(),
        }).success(function(){
            alert("success");
        });
    });
    $('.best_in_place').best_in_place();
});
```

**Routes**

```
 namespace :admin do
    root :to => "dashboard#index"
    resources :dashboard
    resources :albums do
      resources :images do
          put :ajaxUpdate, :on => :collection
      end
     end
    get "admin/album"
    end
```

**Controller**

```
    def ajaxUpdate
        @album = Album.find(params[:album_id])
        @image = @album.images.find(params[:albumcover])
        if @image.update_attributes(params[:image])
            flash[:notice] = "Successfully updated Image"
        else
            render "edit"
        end
    end
```

**View**

```
<% if !@images.blank? %>
    <% @images.each do |image| %>
        <div class="item">
            <div class="image-box">
                <div class="source">
                    <%= image_tag image.source %>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="info">
                <div class="item-links">
                    <%= link_to "Edit", edit_admin_album_image_path(@album, image.id), :id => "edit"%>
                    <%= link_to "Delete", 
                        admin_album_image_path(@album, image.id),
                        :class => "item-link delete-image",
                        :method => :delete, 
                        :remote => true,
                        :confirm => "Are you sure?" %>
                </div>  
                <%= label(:albumcover, 'Set as Album Cover ', :style => "float: left;") %>
                <%= radio_button_tag (:albumcover, image.id, false, :id => :albumcover_tag)  %>  //The Relevant Code
            </div>
        </div>
        <% end %>
    <% else %>
        <p class="alert">No images in this album</p>
    <% end %>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: i think it should be **ajaxUpdate_admin_album_image_path** in your js code

Comment: you can do **rake routes** in your terminal and find the correct name of the method

Comment: I have and it outputs `ajaxUpdate_admin_album_image PUT    /admin/albums/:album_id/images/:id/ajaxUpdate(.:format) admin/images#ajaxUpdate`

Answer (score 0):

To invoke a URL or PATH helper you must append `_url` or `_path` to the route name. And I think the way your route is set up, you don't need the `:admin` argument:

```
# images.js.erb
$.ajax({
  type: 'PUT',
  url: '<%= ajaxUpdate_admin_album_image_url(@album, @image) %>',
  data: $('#albumcover_tag').val(),
}).success(function(){
  alert("success");
});
```

Comment: this still produces the same error.  Should I somehow route it differently? Does the fact that it is called from a nested url( http://localhost:3000/admin/albums/1/images) effect the results?

Comment: No it shouldn't matter at all... Can you post you entire error trace. Does the error show when you load the page where you use the method or when you click on it. If you get the **same** error, you might have used the helper the wrong way somewhere else in your code?

Comment: I errors on page load so I don't even have a chance to try the link.  Do I need to reroute it a different way?